# Download only Weblogic Server Tools plugin for eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, weblogic12c

I have to install the plugin Weblogic Server Tools for Weblogic 12c. I want to install it in an external location to give only plugins folder to other developers.
On Oracle download website, I find only a full OEPE package of 1,4Go, but my previous weblogic 10 plugin size is 60Mo.
Can I find only the Weblogic Server Tools plugin in a zip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to install the plugin via market place, then move the features and plugin folder to an external folder with a link.